# React + Redux + Hook,error in state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am creating a simple Todo app using React JS,Hooks and redux.As per the below code Why can't I update state and retrieve the data ? When I submit the input fields it doesn't show error but I can't retrieve data from Redux state . Mostly there may be error with usage of useSelector function and initialState.

```
# necessary imports,omitted for readers ease.

function FormComp() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const [inputdata,setInputdata] = useState('')

    const handlesubmit =(e)=>{e.preventDefault();
                                dispatch(allActions.formAction.addTodo(inputdata))
    }
    const addtodo = useSelector(state=>state.todo) 

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <input  onChange={(e)=>setInputdata(e.target.value)} value={inputdata} />
                <button onClick={handlesubmit}> submit </button>
            </form>

            {console.log(addtodo)} # console shows undefined 

        </div>
    )
}

export default FormComp
```

REDUCER FUNCTION

```
import { ADDTODO } from "../constants/types";

const initialState={todo:'no todos'}

const toDos = (state=initialState,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case ADDTODO:return{
            ...state,todo:action.payload
                     }
        default:return state        
    }
}


export default toDos
```

ACTION FUNCTION

```
import { ADDTODO } from "../constants/types"


const addTodo=(todo)=>{return {
    type:ADDTODO,
    payload:todo
}}


export default{
    addTodo
}
```

Comment: Please make a **producible** example: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), usually people upload their code to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq).

Comment: Btw your code looks fine, there might be a problem with something that you not showing us. Like wrong value of `ADDTODO`.